# Como fazer uma requisicao e procurar por uma string

Tags: sql, python, string, request

Gostaria de saber como que eu dou uma requisicao e procuro por uma string, exemplo:
*www.site.com/index.php?id=' (Error SQL) (procurar o error)
So estou com problema nisso ja que ta quase tudo pronto, segue o codigo:

```
import os, socket, urllib2
os.system('clear')
while True:
url = raw_input("URL: ") #site para fazer o teste
with open('word') as wordlist: #abrindo a wordlist
lista = [linha.strip() for linha in wordlist] #passando a wordlist para  lista
for list in lista:
     url2 = url.replace(" ", list) #colocando os codigos na url get
     url3 = urllib2.urlopen(url2).read()
              cf =  url3.text
     if (cf.find("Mysql")==-1):
      print "teste deu"
     else:
     print "n deu"
     break
```

Answer (score 0):

Em python objetos do tipo `str` possuem métodos de busca, segue alguns deles:

```
>>> string = 'goiaba'
>>> string.find('a') # Retorna a primeira ocorrência da string passada
3
>>> string.startswith('g') # Verifica se a string começa com a string passada
>>> string.endswith('ba') # Verifica se a string termina com a string passada
```